# How to design a schema for a Mongo DB database

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema

I am a beginner in MongoDB and wish to learn more. At this point I know how to perform CRUD operations in both Mongo shell and using Java drivers. But the next for me is how to design.

I have taken the 'MongoDB for Java Developers' course, which gave me the basic idea about how indexes work, what is sharding & when to use sharding etc.

But now I wish to learn designing a database schema in MongoDB.

I have read the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) on official Mongo site. But couldn't understand some of the things.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Usually such questions are off-topic here on SO as they tend to invite opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. However, a good place to start would be to read the **6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design** series [**Part 1**](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1), [**Part 2**](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2) and [**Part 3**](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3).

Comment: @chridam Thanks for the links :) will go through them.
I don't understand what is off-topic in my question, could you be more specific so that I can improve my question. Thank you once again

Comment: As you are asking for someone to point you in the right direction without actually specifying a problem that could be answered without opinions, that could be deemed off-topic. Would suggest this read [**What exactly is a recommendation question?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) so that you can improve the question and hopefully get better answers.

Comment: @chridam Got it, will edit the question accordingly :)